# Is it possible to run IdentityServer on a private network for MVC authentication?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

I believe the short answer to my question is "No", but allow me to describe the context.

We are currently using IdentityServer to authorize access to our APIs (via client credentials).  All of the API clients are computer programs which run in our data centers and are under our control.  In order to minimize our attack surface, our IdentityServer is running from an internal/private network, reachable from our APIs, services, and other apps.  No problems.

We now want to leverage the IdentityServer installation to provide user authentication for our public-facing web applications.  These applications run via ASP.NET MVC and will consequently require user interaction with the IdentityServer for password validation (implicit or hybrid grant type).  This appears to be a hard requirement, but I'm curious if there is a simple way to maintain the private installation of IdentityServer.

Can we proxy requests from the ASP.NET middle-ware for handling the authentication handshake, and does it even make sense to do so?  I'm leaning towards a public-facing STS to eliminate any proxying, but thought I would ask to see what other patterns are employable.

For what its worth, we would ultimately use cookie-based authentication with the hybrid flow, but would be able to start with the implicit flow too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's browser must be able to access the identity server. This can be via a proxy though.